# Why wont this code return and create the information to a .csv file?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

this is my code below to web scrape the tesco website, which I cant get to work, no error codes are showing but its also not creating a .csv file. any help would be appreciated.

```
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    from selenium import webdriver
    import time 
    import csv

    def save_csv(dct):
    name = "tescowhiskey.csv" 
    print("[INFO] saving...")
    with open(name, 'a', encoding="utf-8") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow((dct['cap'],
    dct['Whiskey'],
    dct['TESCO'],
    ))

    def scroll(driver):
    for _ in range(1,6):
    # driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,  1000)") 
    time.sleep(7)



    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get("https://www.tesco.com/groceries/en-GB/shop/drinks/spirits/whisky")

    for i in range(2):
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
    scroll(driver)
    data = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("product-list-container")
    for d in data:
    items = {}
    body = d.text.split("\n")
    items["cap"] = body[0]
    items["Whiskey"] = body[1]
    items["TESCO"] = body[-3]
    save_csv(items)
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".prev-next").click()



    driver.quit()
```

Comment: please format your code properly

Comment: Especially for python. Indenting your code wrong can result in logic errors.

Comment: You're missing the dot before the class name: `(".product-list-container")`

Comment: Sorry, It is indented properly, it's just been changed when posting on here as it wouldn't let me post otherwise. Thank you for your help Mike67